# Excel: count rows based on one column's value and another column's length

Tags: excel

Let's say I have three columns: Column one is [a,a,b,a,b,c,a]. Column two is [1,(blank),(blank),4,6,1,10]. Column three has a formula, to make every cell equal to column two.

I want a formula that tells me how many rows have "a" for column one and a number in column three. Obviously I can't use countif column three is "<>" because there are formulas in it, so every cell technically has a value.

How do I accomplish this? I don't know if I'm overthinking it, but it's giving me a headache.

Comment: @BigBen It would be something like =b1, copied down. So cell c1 would be =b1, cell c2 would be =b2, etc. The point is more that column c would be entirely made up of formulas, even when what's copied over is blank.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6="a")*(LEN(C1:C6)>0))`?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: "Column three has a formula, to make every cell equal to column two" ? would that be the function `=B1` in C1, and then copied  down ?

Comment: @Luuk Exactly right